# kong gateway request and response body

Tags: gateway, api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I am using `KONG` API gateway to send REST API requests to my microservices in `JSON format`. when I using `KONG` (TCP-http-UDP-file) LOG plugins It shows all details about my requests (headers-status code and etc) except request body.!

The Question is :
how can I receive my request and response body logs with KONG API gateway.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the intention of Kong to not log the body of requests/responses.

> @teunis90(Senior developer at Kong): The request/response body is left out of the logs on purpose as it is not bound (we don't want to log the response body of a video streaming service) and will likely never be, within Kong itself. Please feel free to implement a plugin using the new functionality. [source](https://github.com/Kong/kong/pull/5968#issuecomment-758871605)

Comment: Hi what is your opinion about this custom plugin ?

[custom plugin link](https://github.com/arvind-internet-omuni/kong-tcp-body-log/find/master)

I installed it but is depend on two plugins that I did not found yet
`kong.plugins.log-serializers.runscope` and `kong.tools.public`

Comment: I never use the plugin outside those supported by Kong. but it seems that that plugin is outdated? 
You might be able to configure Nginx to log body and use some kind of log formatted to ship the log instead.